# linq2db logging to file using Karambolo

Tags: c#, logging, linq2db

We are using .NET Core 3.1, [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/3.1.9), [Npgsql 4.1.9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/4.1.9), [Karambolo.Extensions.Logging.File 3.3.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Karambolo.Extensions.Logging.File/3.3.1) and [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore 3.7.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore/3.7.0).

We have the following Karambolo configuration in `appsettings.json`:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "File": {
      "TextBuilderType": "MyProject.Web.Logging.LogEntryTextBuilder, MyProject.Web",
      "BasePath": "AppData/Logs",
      "EnsureBasePath": true,
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      },
      "FileEncoding": "utf-8",
      "DateFormat": "yyyyMMdd",
      "CounterFormat": "000",
      "MaxFileSize": 10485760,
      "IncludeScopes": true,
      "MaxQueueSize": 100,
      "Files": [{
        "Path": "MyProject-<date>-<counter>.log",
        "MinLevel": {
          "MyProject": "Information",
          "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Information",
          "LinqToDB.EntityFrameworkCore": "Information"
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

We also have the following configuration for linq2db logging:

```cs
private void ConfigureLinq2DbConsoleLogging()
{
    DataConnection.TurnTraceSwitchOn();
    DataConnection.WriteTraceLine = (string s1, string s2, TraceLevel tl) => Debug.WriteLine($"{s1}: {s2}");
}
```

However, we can't see any logs related to linq2db in `MyProject-20230331-000.log` file. Our goal is to log all executed SQL queries by linq2db. SQL queries executed by EF Core are logged normally (`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command` namespace).

Comment: It was a long time ago when we added logging for extension. But if you configured LoggingFactory for EF Core, `linq2db` should handle this.